# Which firefox version is compatible with selenium webdriver 3.6.0?

Tags: selenium, firefox, protractor

I'm using Protractor to fulfill my automation needs, The IDE that I'm using is VS code. I was able to run my automation scripts against Chrome, But when it comes to firefox most of my test cases are getting failed. It seems like some compatibility issue to me. Can anyone help me to fix this?

Here are the details of the versions that I currently have on my machine:

**Selenium web driver version: 3.6.0
Firefox version: 57.0
Gecko driver version: 0.19.0**

I have tried installing firefox version 47.0, But it didn't work. It seems that selenium web driver couldn't connect

Answer (score 1):

According to [GeckoDriver documentation](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/geckodriver/Support.html)

1. Selenium users must update to version 3.11 or later to use geckodriver
2. Gecko driver version: 0.19.0 supports Firefox versions from 55 to 62 inclusively

So I believe you have to play with the [webdriver-manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webdriver-manager), theoretically it should be possible to [automate any desktop/mobile browser version](https://experitest.com/real-desktop-mobile-browsers/) given you use matching [Selenium Standalone Server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-standalone) / driver / client